# Using a Lock with redis-py

Tags: python, django, redis

I'm trying to create a lock on a redis value in a django project, but am having trouble. Non blocking code works just fine, ie:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)
data_dict = {'key': 'value'}
r.hmset('hash', data_dict)
```

However when trying to use a lock to prevent other threads from writing to this, with code:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379)
data_dict = {'key': 'value'}
lock = r.lock('hash')
with lock.acquire() as l:
    r.hmset('hash', data_dict)
```

throws:`redis.exceptions.ResponseError: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value`

I apologize if this is a very stupid question but I don't understand how I'm getting that error, the data being set is literally the same

Comment: you have locked ``hash`` key, so you can't set the key in ``r.hmset('hash', data_dict)``

Answer (score 15):

There are two problems:

1. As others have said, you need to use two different keys for the lock and the hash.
2. The syntax is wrong.

To elaborate on point 2, here are the steps involved with using a lock:

1. Create a `Lock` object.
2. Acquire the lock.
3. Do critical stuff.
4. Release the lock.

Without using a context manager (the `with ...` statement), the code might look like this:

```
lock = r.lock('my_lock')
lock.acquire(blocking=True)
r.set('foo', 'bar')
lock.release()
```

With a context manager, that code gets simplified to this:

```
with r.lock('my_lock'):
    r.set('foo', 'bar')
```

What is happening here is the following:

1. `r.lock()` creates and returns a `Lock` object.
2. `Lock.__enter__()` is called automatically, which in turn calls `Lock.acquire()`.
3. The indented code executes.
4. `Lock.__exit__()` is called automatically, which in turn calls `Lock.release()`.

You can see this in the *redis-py* source code.

- [client.py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/b940d073de4c13f8dfb08728965c6ac7c183c935/redis/client.py) (contains `lock()`)
- [lock.py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/blob/a3cfded93afa2a65908f05ac251b18d77fa84dd2/redis/lock.py) (contains the `Lock` class)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/python-redis-lock/ according to this documentation, (if you scroll down to 6th code block, where they mention about django redis), there is no mention on the need to use a diff value for lock , compared to key. whats your reason here that we have to use diff keys?

Comment: @SuperUser the reason is simply that the lock and the (dict) value you are trying to set are two different things, and thus you want two different keys to save them

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set a dictionary in the same key as the lock. You want to have a key for the lock and another for the dictionary.